# Overloading two different type functions with default arguments

Tags: c++, function, overloading

I was doing an assignment and encountered a problem really similar to this: [a-confusion-about-c-function-overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866895/a-confusion-about-c-function-overloading)

I understand why it is ambigious, but I wonder if there is a way to make it work if overloaded function returns different type, i.e.:

```
int foo (int a=0);
double foo (double a=1);
```

and to make this work:

```
double x=foo();
```

Comment: Could you live with `double x = foo<double>()`?

Comment: duplicate of
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442026/function-overloading-by-return-type